# Online poll with randomly-ordered options, supporting images

Tags: gratis, web-apps, survey

I want people to vote for the best image among 10 candidates.

Requirements:

- Randomize the display order, to avoid order bias
- Allow images
- No registration needed
- Creating the poll results in two URLs: one for the poll, one for the results
- Gratis
- Ideally no advertisements

I tried several poll systems supporting images (poll-maker.com, easypolls.net), but they always display candidates in the same order, no randomization, so the poll is biased.

Comment: LimeSurvey would need some [custom scripting](https://www.limesurvey.org/en/forum/can-i-do-this-with-limesurvey/54631-using-pictures-in-ranking-question#57534). If you do that, you can probably also randomize the images

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://pollunit.com

The options are displayed in a table. Pictures can be viewed in a lightbox.

With a Premium Account you should get all your requested features. Only with the two URLs I am not sure if the system is suitable for you. But you can hide the votes of your participants.

Free features:

- Vote for images
- No registration needed

With a premium account you get following additional features:

- No advertisements
- Randomize the order
- Hiding the results (only admins can see the result)

**Disclosure:** I am one of the developers of https://pollunit.com

Comment: Sorry it has to be gratis and have random order.

Comment: @Nicolas Sorry, i missed the "gratis". The random order can only be activated with a payed premium account.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Google Forms? You can easily create a poll with a single multiple-choice question. It's not possible to add images in the answer fields (for now), but you can insert images inside the question itself, then make an answer list of 1 to 10. You can't shuffle the order of the pictures, but you can shuffle the answers.

Registration is not needed for participants, just for you.
The results of the poll can be saved to a Google spreadsheet, allowing you to easily work with the results.

Comment: "Can't shuffle the order of images" is IMHO a killer criteria.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal, but I'm trying to give the best answer I could think of. An alternative is to upload the pictures to a server or photo site and put links to the pictures as answers.